# why isn't share button appearing with jquery / fb js?

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
        $.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_UK/all.js');
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://www.google.com/" data-layout="button_count"></div></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

A demo:

http://www.frostjedi.com/terra/scripts/demo/fb1.html

The share button isn't appearing and idk why. Any ideas?

The code is based off of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/howto/jquery except that the API key isn't being set (although I don't imagine that should make a difference)

Comment: use https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button

Comment: i agree with vitorino. don´t use jquery for this, just use the generated code from the link he posted.

Comment: It doesn't work because you are not calling FB.init

Comment: It doesn't work when I do call `FB.init`...

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong URL for Facebook's script. Change it to this:
`$.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0');`

BTW, you really don't need jQuery for this. The same result can be reached with the following code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://www.google.com/" data-layout="button_count"></div>
```